# JQuery if two conditions are met output message

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to output `success` to the log if two conditions are met in an `if` statement in jQuery.
My click functions are working fine and changing the values. I just can't get the `if` statement to work:

```
<script>
        

        var netflixClicked = 0;
        var primeClicked = 0;
        var searchClicked = 0

        $("#netflix").click(function() {
            netflixClicked = "1";
            console.log('netflix' + ' ' + netflixClicked)
        });
        $("#prime").click(function() {
            primeClicked = "1";
            console.log('prime' + ' ' + primeClicked)
        });
        $("#searchButton").click(function() {
            searchClicked = "1";
            console.log('search' + ' ' + searchClicked)
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ((netflixClicked == 1) && (searchClicked == 1)) {
                console.log('success')
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to run the if statement everytime one is clicked.

Comment: why do mix string type and interger type ?

Comment: in the `$(document).ready(`, the function runs ONCE the document is ready... So on load... Never after.

Comment: Your `if` runs once before anything is clicked.

Comment: Have a nice [reading here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that ?

```js
const BtClick =
  { netflix : 0
  , prime   : 0
  , search  : 0
  } 
$("#netflix, #prime, #search").click(function()
  {
  BtClick[this.id]++
  console.log(this.id , BtClick[this.id] )

  if (BtClick.netflix && BtClick.search) {
    console.log('success')
    }
  })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:70% !important; width:30%; }
.as-console-row         { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
.as-console-row::before { content: 'log:'; font-size: .8em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="netflix" > netflix </button>
<button id="prime"   > prime   </button>
<button id="search"  > search  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
var netflixClicked = 0;
var primeClicked = 0;
var searchClicked = 0

$("#netflix").click(function() {
    netflixClicked = "1";
    console.log('netflix' + ' ' + netflixClicked)
    checkSuccess();
});
$("#prime").click(function() {
    primeClicked = "1";
    console.log('prime' + ' ' + primeClicked)
    checkSuccess();
});
$("#searchButton").click(function() {
    searchClicked = "1";
    console.log('search' + ' ' + searchClicked)
    checkSuccess();
});

function checkSuccess() {
    if ((netflixClicked == 1) && (searchClicked == 1)) {
        console.log('success');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkSuccess();
});
```

Also, sometimes your numbers are numbers, sometimes they are strings.

Comment: could you explain which numbers are strings and which are numbers? hadn't realised

Comment: String has quotes: "1". Number does not have quotes: 1. String: `netflixClicked = "1";`. Do not use quotes.